# left join brining back more records than it should

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to do a simple join and I'm not sure what is going on here. I have two tables: pend_bominv_det which has 305 rows and alldet which has around 12k

I'm trying to get all of the 305 records from pend_bominv_det and only those that match the claim number from alldet. Any ideas?

```
select distinct c_clm

,manager_name
,'exp_bom' as categ
,time_prd_nm
,report_month
,report_year
,report_end_date
from IN.pend_bominv_det a
left outer join IN.alldet
on a.pearl_clmno = c_clm
where a.pearl_clmno is not null 
and time_prd_nm = 'WEEK 2'
```

Comment: post a sqlfiddle to help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there perhaps multiple instances of the same claim number in the pend_bominv_det table? I think you should be using a right join here.

Hope this helps

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN`s are confusing to maintain.  If suggesting switching how the `JOIN` operates, perhaps switching the order of the tables is better than switching from `LEFT` to `RIGHT` `JOIN`.

Comment: Agreed zimdanen. Thank you for improving the answer.